# C# Out of Memory Exception - Image Type

Tags: c#

The intent of this code is to get an unknown number .JPG's from a specified location, and send them to "Microsoft Print to PDF." After about the 5th .jpg image, it throws an "Out of Memory" exception at: `Image img = imgs[index];` How can I tackle this?

**UPDATED: 2016-12-11 @ 9:00 PM** (This problem has been solved with the following code)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Deployment.Application;


namespace CEB_Process
{
public partial class Form1 : Form 
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }




    //Texbox Input
    string Case_No;
    int index = 0;



   private static Image[] _imgs; 
    //==========================================================================================================
    //CONVERT PICTURES TO PDF Button Click
    //==========================================================================================================
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // set the directory to store the output.
        string newdirectory = string.Format(@"C:\{0}", Case_No);

        // generate a file name as the current date/time in unix timestamp format
        string newFileName = "5 x 7 in";

        try
        {

                // initialize PrinterDocument object
                PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument()
                {

                    //Printer Settings
                    PrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings()
                    {
                        // set the printer to 'Microsoft Print to PDF'
                        PrinterName = "Microsoft Print to PDF",

                        // tell the object this document will print to file
                        PrintToFile = true,

                        // set the filename to whatever you like (full path)
                        PrintFileName = Path.Combine(newdirectory, newFileName + ".pdf"),

                    }//End Printer settings


                };//End PrintDocument()

            Page_Init(null, new EventArgs()); 
            pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.pd_PrintPage);
            pd.Print();

        }//End try 

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }//End Button Module   

    public static void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            BuildImageList(); 

    }


    //===========================================
    // Print Event Handler
    //===========================================
    private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
    {

        Graphics graphic = ev.Graphics;
        Point p = new Point(10, 10);
        Image img = _imgs[index];
        graphic.DrawImage(img, p);
        index++;
        ev.HasMorePages = index < _imgs.Length;
        img.Dispose();

    }


    //===============================================
    // Get Build the Image List
    //===============================================

    public static void BuildImageList()
    {
        string sdira = @"C:\test";
        _imgs = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sdira, "*.JPG").Select(f =>         Image.FromFile(f)).ToArray();
    }


 }//End Public Class

}//End Namespace
```

Comment: Where is your pd_PrintPage being invoked from ?

Comment: How many images you are trying to load in `BuildImageList`?

Comment: Please note, I did an update to include all relevant code.Regarding the number of images, this number will be unknown. It could be 5, or it could be 100.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code it seems that you're building an image array as many times as you're calling your **Print_Page** and this may be your problem. You only have to do this once.

Make your Image[] imgs; a local field or property and call **BuildImageList** only once per image batch (per page load or whatever your environment is).

Something like:

```
private static Image[] _imgs;

//==========================================================================================================
    //CONVERT PICTURES TO PDF Button Click
    //==========================================================================================================
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // set the directory to store the output.
        string newdirectory = string.Format(@"C:\{0}", Case_No);

        // generate a file name as the current date/time in unix timestamp format
        string newFileName = "5 x 7 in";

        try
        {

                // initialize PrinterDocument object
                PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument()
                {

                    //Printer Settings
                    PrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings()
                    {
                        // set the printer to 'Microsoft Print to PDF'
                        PrinterName = "Microsoft Print to PDF",

                        // tell the object this document will print to file
                        PrintToFile = true,

                        // set the filename to whatever you like (full path)
                        PrintFileName = Path.Combine(newdirectory, newFileName + ".pdf"),

                    }//End Printer settings


                };//End PrintDocument()


            pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.pd_PrintPage);
            pd.Print();

        }//End try 

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }//End Button Module   


public static void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(!IsPostBack)
     BuildImageList();

}


    //===========================================
    // Print Event Handler
    //===========================================
    private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
    {

        Graphics graphic = ev.Graphics;
        Point p = new Point(10, 10);
        Image img = _imgs[index];
        graphic.DrawImage(img, p);
        index++;
        ev.HasMorePages = index < _imgs.Length;
        img.Dispose();

    }


    //===============================================
    // Get Build the Image List
    //===============================================

    public static void BuildImageList()
    {
        String sdira = @"C:\test";
        _imgs = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sdira, "*.JPG").Select(f => Image.FromFile(f)).ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: It is bad to load all images at once. Better solution is to get all paths to jpeg files first. Then in event handler he should load, draw and dispose expected image.

Comment: I updated my original code (at top) to reflect agfc's suggestions; however, I cannot get it to compile: ("an object reference is required for the non-static field..." `_imgs = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sdira, "*.JPG").Select(f => Image.FromFile(f)).ToArray(); `

Comment: it should work now - it should have either been static or should be initialized before first use.

Comment: @apocalypse - true, this may be better but I didn't want to change the existing code too much.

Comment: @agfc - After adding `Page_Init(null, new EventArgs());` to button2_Click (took me several hours to figure this out :)), everything executed perfectly! Thank you for your help. If you get a chance, any idea how i can get the images to 5" X 7"? The pictures are being saved with something similar to a 500% zoom.